# Start an aliased application from shell passing relative path of a document

Tags: command-line, alias

I "aliased" a shell command in this way:

```
alias "myapplication"="/home/manuel/myapp/bin/startapp.sh"
```

Now i'd like to pass to it a relative file-path where i am when i execute the aliased command, like this:

```
manuel@gemini:~/Desktop/myfolder$ myapplication myfile.xml
```

but the aliased application get only the filename `myfile.xml`

Should i add something in the alias lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aliases do not do arguments. You need a shell function for this:

```
function myapplication() { /home/manuel/myapp/bin/startapp.sh "$@" ;}
```

Now you can call myapplication() with:

```
myapplication myfile.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Rinzwind, but it doesn't work :(. I added the function you wrote in .bashrc, now shell has the command "myapplication", but it still load "myfile.xml", not "path/where/i/am/myfile.xml". Why?

Comment: ah I misunderstood your question then, sorry :P htorque's answer might be better (but we need the source of your script to know that for sure ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies within your application. If you want to get the absolute path from a relative one, try this one in your application/script:

```
abs_path=$(readlink -m "$1")
```

Comment: Ok, i substitute $@ with $(readlink -m "$1") in the function that calls .sh file and now it works. Both of you are right. Thanks